# How to stop infinite loop for UPC check code

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, barcode, infinite

my code has an infinite loop and I cannot seem to break it.  Also, when inserting a blank line, I am told that there is an index error.  Please help!

The first step of checking a valid UPC is adding the odd position digits and multiplying by three, then you add that number to the sum of the even position digits.  Then compute the remainder when divided by 10.  If the remainder is not zero, subtract this remainder from 10 to get the check digit.  If the remainder is zero, then the check digit should be 0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
            String enterUPC = in.nextLine();
            int length = enterUPC.length();
            int checkDigit=0;

          char char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7, char8, char9, char10, char11, char12;
          int num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9, num10, num11, num12;


          char1 = enterUPC.charAt(0);
          num1 = Character.getNumericValue(char1); 
          char2 = enterUPC.charAt(1);
          num2 = Character.getNumericValue(char2); 
          char3 = enterUPC.charAt(2);
          num3 = Character.getNumericValue(char3); 
          char4 = enterUPC.charAt(3);
          num4 = Character.getNumericValue(char4); 
          char5 = enterUPC.charAt(4);
          num5 = Character.getNumericValue(char5); 
          char6 = enterUPC.charAt(5);
          num6 = Character.getNumericValue(char6); 
          char7 = enterUPC.charAt(6);
          num7 = Character.getNumericValue(char7); 
          char8 = enterUPC.charAt(7);
          num8 = Character.getNumericValue(char8); 
          char9 = enterUPC.charAt(8);
          num9 = Character.getNumericValue(char9); 
          char10 = enterUPC.charAt(9);
          num10 = Character.getNumericValue(char10); 
          char11 = enterUPC.charAt(10);
          num11 = Character.getNumericValue(char11); 
          char12 = enterUPC.charAt(11);
          num12 = Character.getNumericValue(char12); 



            while(length > 0) {
                //Algorithm Step One and Algorithm Step Two
                int stepOne = (num1 + num3 + num5 + num7 + num9 + num11) * 3;
                int stepTwo = stepOne + (num2 + num4 + num6 + num8 + num10);

                while (length == 12) {
                //Algorithm Step Three
                if(stepTwo%10!=0) {
                    checkDigit = 10 - (stepTwo%10);
                }
                else {
                    checkDigit = 0;}

                System.out.println("Check digit should be : " + checkDigit);
                System.out.println("Check digit is: " + num12);

                }
            }
                if(checkDigit == num12) {
                    System.out.println("UPC is valid");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("UPC is not valid");
                }


                if (length == 0){
                    System.out.println("ERROR! UPC MUST have exactly 12 digits");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.print("Goodbye!");
                }

            } 
    }
```

Comment: First of all you are never decrementing length, and second of all, when you have variable names with the same name, but different number suffixes then that should be a huge red flag that you should be using arrays (or collections).

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loops are checking the variable `length`, but you are not changing it inside the loop. Therefore, the loop never ends.

If you want to repeatedly read a number from the scanner and perform the UPC algoithm, then the reading, breaking into digits and calculation of the length should all be inside the loop. If you only want to do this once, there shouldn't be a loop there at all.

Your loop condition should not check the length, because everything has been moved inside. Instead, create either a do-while loop or an infinite while loop:

```
while ( true ) {

    System.out.println("Enter a UPC (enter a blank line to quit): ");
    String enterUPC = in.nextLine();
    int length = enterUPC.length();

    if ( length == 0 ) {
        break;
    }

    // All the rest of the processing is done here.

}
```

Note that this loop should be right after your definition of the scanner. And the way it finishes is by checking the length after the user enters. This is why there is an `if` statement there.

Comment: Can you please show me where in the code this should be? I moved everything inside of the loop, and it is still infinite.

Comment: @Michael OK, I have edited my answer with a snippet showing the loop, and what was moved inside. I hope it is more helpful now.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  One more quick question -- how do you break the loop now because once the program is run, it automatically will ask again for a new UPC code to be input.  Thank you!

Comment: @Michael As I wrote, the loop breaks in the `if` statement. If the user enters a blank line, the `if` condition becomes true, and then the `break` statement will break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrement length in your while loops, otherwise length will always be equal to 12 or greater than 0, etc. Also, you may want to consider using an ints rather than typing out all those declarations. You could then loop through them using a for loop with a temp char variable so you don't have to initialize all of them like that. Your for loop could look like this:

```
char[] arrayChars = new char[enterUPC.length()];
int[] arrayInts = new int[enterUPC.length()];
for(int i=0;i<enterUPC.length();i++) {
   char temp=enterUPC.charAt(0);
   num[i] = Character.getNumericValue(temp);
}
```

Then in your while loop, loop through the int array and add all the 0+all the even indices and multiply by 3 and add all the odd indices. 
Also, you never check if the line is blank.